# Passing mutilple HTML fragments / other components to a component

Tags: aurelia

Consider a simple component in Aurelia:

```
export class FrameComponent
{
    @bindable str1;
    @bindable str2;
}
```

And the corresponding HTML template:

```
<template>
    ${str1}
    ${str2}
</template>
```

As simple as it gets. Now I can use this component in a parent like this:

```
<template>
    <require from="./frame-component"></require>
    <frame-component str1="Hello" str2="World"></frame-component>
</template>
```

**Question 1**

What if I don't want to provide the child component just with simple strings, but instead I want to set them with HTML fragments?

**Question 2**

What if the I want to pass whole complete components as in `str1` and `str2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a gist demo: https://gist.run/?id=0bf83980935015217cfb83250643c13f

**Content Projection**

It applies for **Question 1 and Question 2**.

[[Documentation]](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-content-projection/1)
By using slots, you can define the content of your custom component declaratively. It can contain other custom components as well.

`frame-slot.html`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="str1">Default str1</slot>
  </div>

  <div>
    <slot name="str2">Default str2</slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

usage in `app.html`

```
<require from="./frame-slot"></require>

<frame-slot>
    <div slot="str1"><h3>${slotStr1}</h3></div>
    <div slot="str2">
        <h3>${slotStr2}</h3>
        <div>
            <frame-slot></frame-slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</frame-slot>
```

**Inline ViewStrategy**

It applies for **Question 1 and Question 2**.

[[Documentation]](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/api/aurelia/templating/latest/class/InlineViewStrategy)
By using InlineViewStrategy, you can define templates as plain string variables and display it with the help of `<compose>` element [[Composition docs]](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-basics/4).

`frame-inline.js`

```
import { bindable, InlineViewStrategy } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class FrameInline {
  @bindable template;
  @bindable model;

  viewStrategy;

  attached() {
    this.viewStrategy = new InlineViewStrategy(`<template>${this.template}</template>`);
  }
}
```

`frame-inline.html`

```
<template>
  <compose view.bind="viewStrategy" model.bind="model"></compose>
</template>
```

`app.js`

```
export class App {

  inlineModel = { 
    name: "inline-template",
    description: "This is an inline template",
    slot: "Frame-slot Str1 content within frame-inline"
  };

  inlineTemplate = '<require from="./frame-slot"></require>' + 
                   '<div>${model.name}: ${model.description}</div>' + 
                   '<br>' +
                   '<frame-slot>' + 
                     '<div slot="str1">${model.slot}</div>' +
                   '</frame-slot>';
}
```

usage in `app.html`

```
<require from="./frame-inline"></require>
<frame-inline template.bind="inlineTemplate" model.bind="inlineModel"></frame-inline>
```

**InnerHTML binding**

It applies for **Question 1** only.

You can bind content to an element's innerHTML property. I'm mentioning that, but you should use it with caution or not at all.

[[Documentation]](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/5)

> Binding using the innerhtml attribute simply sets the element's innerHTML property. The markup does not pass through Aurelia's templating system. Binding expressions and require elements will not be evaluated.

```html
<div innerHTML.bind="content | sanitizeHTML"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome answer!